# Using Zurb Foundation tooltip outside of the framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to use the zurb foundation tooltip script without loading any of the other foundation library for my site but when I try to load it, it's throwing this js error.

My mark-up looks something like this:

```
<span class="has-tip tip-right" data-width="200" title="This is a tip">This is a tip</span>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.foundation.tooltips.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

JS error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tooltips' app.js:5
(anonymous function) app.js:5
fire jquery.js:1075
self.fireWith jquery.js:1193
jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js:435
DOMContentLoaded jquery.js:949
```

Here is how I'm loading the script

```
(function ($) {  

$(function(){
    // initialize tooltips
    $(document).tooltips();
});
})(jQuery);
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Can you post the full HTML page? There is either a reference to jQuery missing or your js references are out of order.

Comment: I've included a snippet of the mark-up, theres the essential bits, there are 3 script reference at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you aren't calling the function by the correct name. It should be `$(document).foundationTooltips()` and **NOT** `$(document).tooltips()`

Full example:

```
(function ($) {  

$(function(){
    // initialize tooltips
    $(document).foundationTooltips(); //This line right here
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

The new doc should have this:

```
<span data-tooltip class="has-tip tip-right" data-width="200" title="This is a tip">This is a tip</span>
```

Notice the "data-tooltip".  That is very hard to find documented right now.

Comment: as in - it isn't documented at all, just shown in an example snippet

Answer (score 0):

Foundation tooltips appears to use the title attribute as a default tooltip as do most tooltip libraries. data-tooltip is a custom field used only by someone who wants to use it themselves - not as a documented item. Google "data attributes in html5".